# Is there a way of adding an item to a dictionary within an if statement with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, game-development

I am making a text-based adventure game, and am trying to add an item to a directory on the basis that the player has a key in their inventory.

I have tried every solution I could find, and none of them worked. I think this is maybe because I have a different syntax to the other dictionaries.

```
    if 'key' in inventory:
    print('Well done for killing all monsters on the first floor! You can 
    now 
    travel upstairs from the hall')
    'Hall' ['upstairs'] = 'Landing'

     'Hall' : {
              'south' : 'Kitchen',
              'east'  : 'Dining Room',
              'north' : 'Library',
              'west' : 'Game Room',
            },
```

Please tell me another way to put

```
    'Hall' ['upstairs'] = 'Landing'
```

without changing all of the directory, as I have numerous other rooms.

Comment: what exactly is the type of 'Hall'?

Comment: Um `'Hall' ['upstairs'] = 'Landing'` is trying to use index-based assignment into a *string*, `'Hall'` with another string as a key.

Comment: @junapa.arrivillaga: This is just one of the previous solutions that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned your "different syntax", which I am not familar with - so I guess this is actually where your problems arise. See my Adaptations bellow - is this the behavior you expected?

```
Hall = {
    'south': 'Kitchen',
    'east': 'Dining Room',
    'north': 'Library',
    'west': 'Game Room',
}

inventory = ['key']

if 'key' in inventory:
    print('Well done for killing all monsters on the first floor! You can now travel upstairs from the hall')
    Hall['upstairs'] = 'Landing'

print(Hall)
# Output: {'south': 'Kitchen', 'east': 'Dining Room', 'north': 'Library', 'west': 'Game Room', 'upstairs': 'Landing'}
```

**Note:** You need to define your dictionary `Hall` before you can assign key-value-pairs like this `Hall['upstairs'] = 'Landing'`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I tried removing the quotation marks and it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly didnt work? Have you tried running my Code?

Comment: I tried the exact same thing when testing a previous would-be solution. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: so is it solved? Or which issue / error do you get now? (Thanks for accepting my answer)

Comment: Okay nice, no worries - just wanted to make sure - have fun with your game (in case it is public it would be nice to see a link here in the comments once you finished it, at least I do think so).